# New Laptop LCD inverter Fitted but Brightness Controls not Working

Tags: laptop, lcd

The inverter board for my laptop (Vaio FE series) LCD panel is buzzing loudly when the brightness controls are adjusted down though not when on maximum. There is also screen flickering so I suspect it's about to fail. I have sourced a replacement which works, but the screen is significantly dimmer and the brightness controls no longer function.

The original inverter was Tamura branded model HBL-0341 dual lamp inverter. The new inverter is the same design though with a lot less circuits (edit: components).

Questions:

- What is likely fault with the old board and can it be repaired?
- Why can the brightness not be adjusted with the new board?

Edit: picture added, old board top, new board bottom.[image: inverter boards]

Comment: "same design though with a lot less circuits." what defines it as the same design?  Sounds to me like the replacement isn't an *exact* replacement, and those differences are why you are having issues.

Comment: *similar design. I appreciate that may be the cause of the issues but I would have expected given the part numbers are the same then brightness control function would work.

Comment: I completely agree that it should.  Now, are you talking about the part numbers printed on the inverters themselves, or part numbers printed on stickers stuck to each inverter, or the part number on the receipt for the part you received?

Comment: The part number printed on the board. There are two: HBL-0341 & E-P1-50321F, printed on both boards. Ordinarily I'd purchase one that looks exactly the same i.e Tamura manufactured but so far they are only available used or as an import. I'm thinking maybe the original can be repaired.

Comment: It is unusual that both inverters are tagged with the same part numbers, but not exactly the same in design.  The issues you describe are those of using the wrong inverter (illumination, but no extra functions), and the visual inspection aside from the part numbers seem to confirm that.

Comment: I replaced the faulty board with a used Tamura board matching the one above (top). The brightness controls now work. There does appear to be one significant component difference between the boards (in the middle with the black plastic top). My electronics knowledge is sadly pitiful so I'm unable to say what it is and whether it is relevant.

Comment: @archery1234 do you remember where you got the inverter? I need the same one and also bought one with the same part number which worked for about 10 seconds and then self-destructed :(